# VBA script to find values and update with new data

Tags: excel, vba

So I am building a VBA Script where I am using it look at orders that are received where we would say if they are ok to fulfil or not as imaged. [image]

so I got the script where it adds this to another sheet as an archive so when it next refreshes it excludes the items that have already been answered with a yes or no.
what I want to do is continue the script so that if the data has changed from either blank or cannot yet provide a date it uses the unique ID in column COMB as a search function and then replace the data that was moved in my archive tab without adding a new duplicate line

Not tried anything as can't get my head around the best way

Comment: It's always a good idea to include the code you already have and explain what you already tried.  Questions with no code and/or no specific problem description tend to get closed here.  You can use `Match()` or `Find()` to locate any matching row on your archive worksheet.

Comment: What if you change your existing macro to only copy the rows that already have a yes or a no? It sounds like you only want / need rows with a yes / no in your archive?